# How do i write Group By query for datetime field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I need to group by only date without time from datetime field in table.What can i do friends?

Here My Table field is,

[image]

My Mysql query is,

```
select *,count(ord_number) as ord from tbl_order_details inner join tbl_users on tbl_users.user_id=tbl_order_details.user_id  where 1=1 group by ord_date order by ord asc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by **DATE()**

**Example** -

```
group by DATE(ord_date)
```

**Try this**

```
select *,count(ord_number) as ord from tbl_order_details inner join tbl_users on tbl_users.user_id=tbl_order_details.user_id  where 1=1 group by DATE(ord_date) order by ord asc
```

Answer (score 1):

use DATE() function

```
select *,count(ord_number) as ord from tbl_order_details inner join 
tbl_users on tbl_users.user_id=tbl_order_details.user_id  where 1=1 
group by DATE(ord_date) order by ord asc
```